# MVC creating multiple objects from single view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

*Just to make it clear, my question is how do you **CREATE** multiple objects using a single view. My ViewModel works fine, I can **display** multiple objects **no problem**.*

Its been a while between .NET coding (last time I was coding in 2.0). I have created an MVC 4 project and successfully created a ViewModel (displaying data on a single view from multiple objects).

However, I cheated. I populated the database directly. I now face the question in reverse, what is the best practice for creating multiple objects from a single view?

In my example, I have a *User*, who has a *userId*. The *userId* is a foreign key in *UserDetails*.

Just trying to get back into the swing of it and wondering what you guys do?

Comment: You've tagged your question with ViewModel... that's the way I'd do it!

Comment: Your view model carries all of the relevant information from your view to your controller, your controller populates your various DTOs from the data in the view model and communicates with the database. Job done. Add additional abstraction layers between controller and DB as applicable.

Answer (score 4):

There are 6 ways to pass multiple object in MVC

1. ViewModel
2. Partial View
3. ViewBag
4. ViewData
5. TempData
6. Tuple

Each one have there own pros and cons.you have to decide base on your issue in hand.
For more information you can refer code project article on it: [How to Choose the Best Way to Pass Multiple Models in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/717941/How-to-Choose-the-Best-Way-to-Pass-Multiple-Models)

Let me give advantage and disadvantage of View Model

**ViewModel :
Advantages**

- ViewModel allows us to render multiple model types in a View as a
  single model.
- Great intellisense support and compile time error checking on View
  page.
- ViewModel is good for security purpose also as Views have only what
  they exactly need. Core domain models are not exposed to user.
- If there is any change in core domain model, you do not need to
  change anywhere in View code, just you need to modify corresponding
  ViewModel.

**Disadvantages**

- ViewModels add another layer between Models and Views so it increases
  the complexity a little bit. So for small and demo applications, we
  can use tuple or other ways to keep the things simple for demo.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**
The best approach is to use strongly typed views with Model or ViewModel.

For Example, you have two classes `User` and `Education`, you want to display all education details of user in a view, you can create a custom view model and pass it to view, where you view is strongly typed view model:

```
public class User
{

public int UserId {get;set;}
public string UserName {get;set}
-------
------
}

public class Education
{
public int UserId {get;set;}
public int DegreeId {get;set;}
public long Marks {get;set;}
---------------
--------------
}
```

Now create a view Model like this:

```
public class EducationViewModel
{

public User user {get;set;}
public List<Education> educationList {get;set;}
}
```

now pass the ViewModel to View and do this in View:

```
@model AppNameSpace.ViewModels.EducationViewModel
```

**Tip:** Create a folder named ViewModels and put all the viewmodel classes in it.

**Option2:** 
Option 2 is to user **ViewBag** and pass multiple object from control to your view, **ViewBag** is accessible when you set some value in it in controller, you can access in the view of that action, after that it is automatically washed out, and its null if you access again it.

you can use ViewBag like this:

```
ViewBag.Message = "Using ViewBag";
```

and read value like this in View:

```
string Message = ViewBag.Message as string;
```

**Option 3:**

Option 3 is to store data in **TempData**, its once read only, means you set value in it, and when you read it, its automatically removed, TempData internally uses Session Variables.You can use TempData like this:

```
TempData["Key"] = "value";
```

now you read it in view:

```
string val = TempData["Key"] as string;
```

after reading it, it will be automatically removed, but you can keep it if you need it further  like this:

```
TempData.Keep("Key");
```

Comment: Thanks,This is for displaying data, not creating object.

Comment: what do you means actually creating multiple objects in view?